# Como comparar somente datas no Sequelize?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou usando o ORM Sequelize e gostaria de comparar somente uma data ao invés da data com horário.

Tenho a seguinte data: `2021-05-06 03:00:00.0000000 +00:00`

E estou fazendo assim:

```
const dataAtual = new Date()
const lista = await myRepository.findAll({
  where: {
    dt_end: {[Op.lt]: dataAtual }
  }
});
```

Eu gostaria de comparar

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela
WHERE dt_end < '2021-05-06'
```

Estou usando o SQL Server

Como posso comparar somente a data: `2021-05-06` e descartar o resto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `sequelize.fn` pra converter um `datetime` para `date`.

```js
sequelize.fn("date", myRepository.dt_end);
```

A função vai converter o `2021-05-06 03:00:00.0000000 +00:00` para `2021-05-06`.

Dá uma olhada nessa questão [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723420/convert-datetime-to-date-of-a-column-in-where-condition-using-sequelize).

Comment: Valeu, deu pra ter uma ideia!